PlatformException (PlatformException(error, com.example.profinance_client: Targeting S+
I've being working on a flutter app, I need scheduled notifications so I installed flutter_local_notifications.
When I try to call zoneSchedule, I get this error
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, com.example.profinance_client: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.profinance_client: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.   
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkPendingIntent(PendingIntent.java:428)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:731)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:718)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedScheduleNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:365)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1100)
    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1004)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
))

My code
static Future<void> scheduleNotification({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required TZDateTime scheduledDate,
}) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id',
      'your_channel_name',
      'your_channel_description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
    );
    const IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        IOSNotificationDetails();
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      scheduledDate,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

Configuration - NotificationsHelper.dart:
static Future<void> init() async {
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings();
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
}

Main function (main.dart):
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

tz.initializeTimeZones();
final timezoneName = DateTime.now().timeZoneName;

if (timezoneName != "GMT") {
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timezoneName));
}

final initializationSettingsAndroid =
      new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
  );

build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

     defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

    compileOptions {
         coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.profinance_client"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
}

Dependencies
timezone: ^0.8.0
syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^24.1.45+2
fl_chart: ^0.64.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^8.1.1+1

I've tried to configure, uninstalling the library and updating it to get it work.

Upgrade flutter_local_notifications dependency.

Try this: Inside your app/build.gradle update the targestSdkVersion and minSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.profinance_client"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }


If you get an error related to multidex then add multidex also
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.profinance_client"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
//Inside dependencies

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}



